# Add Foreign Key to information_schema.tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-keys, check-constraints

I would like to have a table with a column that references another table (not reference a column in another table).

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

So i have tblA, tblB and tblC.
tblA has a colum "OtherTable" of varchar.
I want a Foreign Key Contraint that only allows the values "tblA", "tblB" or "tblC" as values in this column.

I tried it with a normal Foreign Key

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblA
ADD FOREIGN KEY (OtherTable)
REFERENCES information_schema.tables(TABLE_NAME);
```

And got the following Error:

> Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>
> Foreign key 'FK__tblA__Tabel__27CED166' references invalid table
>   'information_schema.tables'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>
> Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I also tried it with a Check Constraint

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblA
ADD CHECK (OtherTable IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables));
```

But this also gives me an Error:

> Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>
> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions
>   are allowed.

Is it possible to have this kind of Constraint?

Comment: If nothing else works, try a trigger based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Information_schema.tables is a view, you can't reference a view in a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Build your own list of allowed values (user-def table) and reference it. Better choice is to store readable value which says "why" you have to look for data in some other table e.g. `record type`. And check out other questions about polymorphic data structures - seems to me you are building something similar.

And you should beware of FK-referencing system tables. Those tables are not parts of your application.